# Unable to post Data using NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: php, ios, iphone, nsurlconnection, nsmutableurlrequest

i am using this piece of code i am sending value using "hex string" but data is not posted to

```
"http://localhost/adi/adnan.php"
```

and this is my code

```
       NSLog(@"offset: %i colors: RGB A %i %i %i  %i",offset,red,green,blue,alpha);
       NSString *hexString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X%02X%02X",red,green,blue];
       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/adi/adnan.php"];
       NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
       NSString *messageBody = hexString;
       NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [messageBody length]];
       [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
       [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
       [theRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
       [theRequest setHTTPBody:[messageBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
       NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if(theConnection)
                     {
    NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&err];
    NSLog(@"responseData here is: %@", responseData);
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"responseData: %@", str);           
    receivedata=[NSMutableData data];
    NSLog(@"data is: %@",receivedata);
          }
```

this is my php code

```
<?php
    echo "Engr.Adnan;

 // $abc= $_GET['name'];

  $abc = $_POST['action'];
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    echo $adnan = strrev($abc);

?>
```

and i get this type of output or response

```
2013-12-17 01:33:55.615 VBColorPicker[25216:c07] offset: 27744 colors: RGB A 52 255 36  255
2013-12-17 01:33:55.650 VBColorPicker[25216:c07] Connection Successful
2013-12-17 01:33:55.674 VBColorPicker[25216:c07] responseData: <456e6772 2e41646e 616e4172 7261790a 280a290a>
2013-12-17 01:33:55.675 VBColorPicker[25216:c07] responseData: Engr.AdnanArray
(
)
2013-12-17 01:33:55.675 VBColorPicker[25216:c07] data is: <>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the parameter name from the form data:

```
NSString *hexString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X%02X%02X", red, green, blue];
```

It should be

```
NSString *hexString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"color=%02X%02X%02X", red, green, blue];
```

and then retrieve it server-side like this

```
$color = $_POST['color'];
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to specify a parameter name, you can get the full request body server-side like this:

```
$requestBody = file_get_contents('php://input'); // will be the hex string
```